# MATLAB - Find repeated values in a column and extract values from that row

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix with repeated values in the 1st column, for example:

```
A = [
1  34  463;
2  45  684;
2  23  352;
3  31  256;
1  46  742;
4  25  234]
```

Using `A`, I am looking to extract data from the 2nd column for each value in the 1st column to output `B`. Where repetition occurs for a value in the 1st column, the corresponding values in the 2nd column are put in an additional output column (NaNs can be used where no repetition occurs). For example:

```
B = [
1  34  46;
2  45  23;
3  31  NaN;
4  25  NaN]
```

(The 1st column in `B` is not necessary, but is included here for clarification)

I have attempted to use a combination of find functions, `if` statements and loops, but without success. Ideally, a successful approach would also be efficient, as the actual dataset is large.

I use version R2012a. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`cell-arrays`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) for these kind of problem. Cell Arrays are used when the length of all columns or all rows are not equal. Each row/column could have different size. They don't need padding to make them all equal in size.

One approach using [`accumarray`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html)

```
[~,~,idx] = unique(A(:,1));
outC = accumarray(idx,A(:,2),[],@(x) {x.'})    %//'
%// If you want the outputs in sorted order use the following code instead
%// outC = accumarray(idx,A(:,2),[],@(x) {sort(x).'})

outC = 

[1x2 double]
[1x2 double]
[        31]
[        25]
```

You could access each cell using the syntax like this `outC{1}`

```
>> outC{1}

ans =

46    34
```

If you want to view the whole matrix at once, you could use [`celldisp`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/celldisp.html) function

```
>> celldisp(outC)

outC{1} =
46    34

outC{2} =
23    45

outC{3} =
31

outC{4} =
25
```

If you want to get the output as `NaN` padded matrix instead of cell-array, you could do something like this (after you have obtained `outC` above):

Approach using [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`cellfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)

```
lens = cellfun(@numel,outC);
maxSize = max(lens);
out = nan(maxSize,numel(outC));
mask = bsxfun(@le,(1:maxSize).',lens(:).')
out(mask) = horzcat(outC{:});
out = out.'
```

**Output:**

```
out =

46    34
23    45
31   NaN
25   NaN
```

If you use alternative approach (output sorted) to find the `outC`, the result would be:

```
out =

34    46
23    45
31   NaN
25   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. However, when I test this on my actual dataset, I get the following error: `Error using accumarray. 
First input SUBS must contain positive integer subscripts.` Other than size, the only significant difference is that the actual 1st column begins with zero - could this be the source of the error?

Comment: There might be zeros or negative numbers in the first column, so maybe use `unique` to get unique IDs.

Comment: @Divakar, sure will edit. Guess you have done that already. ;)

Answer (score 3):

This would be one approach -

```
[~,~,idx] = unique(A(:,1),'stable') %// Find IDs for each element from col-1
[~,sorted_idx] = sort(idx)  %// Get sorted IDs
grp_vals = A(sorted_idx,2)  %// Get second column elements grouped together
grp_lens = accumarray(idx,1)%// Find Group lengths

%// Create a mask for a 2D array where the ones are places where grouped 
%// elements are to be put.
mask = bsxfun(@le,[1:max(grp_lens)]',grp_lens(:).') 

%// Create a nan filled array of same shape as mask and finally fill masked 
%// places with grouped elements. Transpose at the end to get desired output.
out = nan(size(mask))
out(mask) = grp_vals
out = out.'
```

Sample run -

```
>> A,out
A =
     1    34   463
     2    45   684
     0    23   352
    -3    31   256
     1    46   742
     4    25   234
     1    12    99
    -3   -20    56
out =
    34    46    12
    45   NaN   NaN
    23   NaN   NaN
    31   -20   NaN
    25   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks. While it works in this example, the sorting is an issue when applied to my dataset. The output values do not correspond to the correct row.